# Total from text file

Tags: python

I have a text file with the data with numbers of good and bad of a product by each gender

```
Male      100 120 
Female    110 150
```

How can I calculate the total from this text file for both gender so that it prints out 480

Here is my attempt to code:

```
def total():
    myFile = open("product.txt", "r")
    for result in myFile:
        r = result.split()            
        print(r[1]+r[2])


total()
```

It prints outs what the column has but it doesn't add them

Comment: It isn't making an attempt to add them, so why don't you *actually try?*

Comment: How about converting a string to integer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by *jonrsharpe*, you aren't adding the previous values.

Since you want to add everything, keep track of the previous values and add the new lines (all converted to integer). Change your code to:

```
def total():
    t = 0
    with open("product.txt", "r") as myFile:
        for result in myFile:
            r = result.split()
            t += int(r[1]) + int(r[2])
    return t
print(total()) # 480
```

Since this got chosen, I'm editing to include file closing.
Mentioned by *Martin Evans*:

> Using with will automatically close the file for you.

Comment: I think you forgot to close the file, or use with key word.

Answer (score 1):

The result of `split` is a sequence of strings, not of integers.
"Adding" two strings with `+` concatenates the strings.

Example interaction with enough clues for you to solve it:

```
>>> s = "123 456"
>>> ss = s.split()
>>> ss
['123', '456']
>>> ss[0] + ss[1]
'123456'
>>> int(ss[0])
123
>>> int(ss[1])
456
>>> int(ss[0]) + int(ss[1])
579
```

When you get unexpected results, opening your interpreter and looking at things interactively usually provides plenty of clues.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert each of the split text entries into an integer, and keep a running total as follows:

```
def total():
    the_total = 0

    with open("product.txt", "r") as myFile:
        for result in myFile:
            r = result.split()            
            the_total += int(r[1]) + int(r[2])

    return the_total

print(total())
```

This would display:

```
480
```

Using `with` will automatically close the file for you.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another one

```
def total():
    with open('product.txt') as f:
        nums = (int(el) for r in f for el in r.split()[1:])
        return sum(nums)

print(total())
```

It works for any number of columns you may have in each row

e.g. with four columns

```
Male   111 222 333 444
Female 666 777 888 999
```

produces

```
4440
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> def total():
        myfile = open("/home/prashant/Desktop/product.txt" , "r")
        for res in myfile:
                r = res.split()
                print (int(r[0])+int(r[1]))
```

str isn't converted into int that's your problem